# How to count matches in several matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, count

Making a dichotomous study, I have to count how many times a condition takes place?
The study is based on two kinds of matrices, ones with forecasts and others with analyzed data.
Both in the forecast and analysis matrices, in case a condition is satisfied we add 1 to a counter. This process is repeated for a points distributed in a grid.
Are there any functions in MATLAB that help me with counting or any script that supports this procedure?

Thanks guys!

EDIT:
The case goes about precipitation registered and forecasted. When both exceed a threshold I consider it as a hit. I have Europe divided in several grid points, and I have to count how many times the forecast is correct. I also have 50 forecasts for each year, so the result (hit/no hit) must be a cumulative action.
I've trying with `count` and `sum` functions, but they reduce the spatial dimension of the matrices.

Comment: SO classic first comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Also, clarify with an example or something similar what you start with and what you want to end with.

Comment: @Luis Please show what matches you want to count...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you are trying to do but the following may help.

```
 forecasted = [ 40 10 50 0 15];
 registered = [ 0 15 30 0 10];
 mismatch = abs( forecasted - registered );
 maxDelta = 10;
 forecastCorrect = mismatch <= maxDelta
 totalCorrectForecasts = sum(forecastCorrect)
```

Results:

```
forecastCorrect =  

 0     1     0     1     1


 totalCorrectForecasts =

 3
```